# Object Serialization to XML with its Element Name having a Sequence Number

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented object serialization for converting my object into an XML string using **XmlSerializer.Serialize(...)** method.

Presently the following XML is being generated by the serializer:

```
<MyAddress>
  <row>
    <Home>1</Home>
    <Office>2</Office>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Home>1</Home>
    <Office>2</Office>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Home>1</Home>
    <Office>2</Office>
  </row>
</MyAddress>
```

But I want the following XML to be generated:

```
<MyAddress>
  <row1>
    <Home>1</Home>
    <Office>2</Office>
  </row1>
  <row2>
    <Home>1</Home>
    <Office>2</Office>
  </row2>
  <row3>
    <Home>1</Home>
    <Office>2</Office>
  </row3>
</MyAddress>
```

Classes being used in my C# code is given below:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyAddress
    {
        public List<row> Rows { get; set; }
    }


    public class row
    {
        public string Home { get; set; }
        public string Office { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't. For this to happen you need to implement your own XML serializer/deserializer.

Comment: Would a "rowNumber" property on "row" not be easier to deal with?

Comment: @ChrisMcAtackney or even a `row` attribute. The problem is getting the index in the list to be serialized.

Comment: @ChrisMcAtackney nope...I know it would have been better to use an attribute in the row element... I am trying to replicate the XML as it it generated by the legacy application.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `XmlAttribute` your `Row` class to store the index, and then sort the items. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var address = new MyAddress();

        address.Rows = new List<Row>();

        var rows = new List<Row>();
        rows.Add(new Row { Home = "Home A" });
        rows.Add(new Row { Home = "Home B" });
        rows.Add(new Row { Home = "Home B" });

        var items = rows.Select((x, index) => new Row 
        {
            Home = x.Home,
            Office = x.Office,
            Index = ++index
        });

        address.Rows.AddRange(items);

        var xmlS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyAddress));
        xmlS.Serialize(Console.Out, address);
    }
}

public class MyAddress
{
    public MyAddress()
    {
        Rows = new List<Row>();
    }

    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public string Home { get; set; }

    public string Office { get; set; }
}
```

That should result in the following XML:

```
<MyAddress>
  <row Index="1">
    <Home>1</Home>
    <Office>2</Office>
  </row>
  <row Index="2">
    <Home>1</Home>
    <Office>2</Office>
  </row>
  <row Index="3">
    <Home>1</Home>
    <Office>2</Office>
  </row>
</MyAddress>
```

Comment: This might not help me in my scenerio, I am trying to regenerate the XML as in the legacy application. Changing the xml structure will render the existing xml useless.

Comment: Tricky situation, since you cannot achieve what you want via XmlSerialization. I suggest you use my code, and then run another algorithm, replace `<row Index="1">` with `<row1>`. A kind of search and replace. In other words, read the XML generated by the above code into a string (line by line, or all in one, you're choice) and do a search/replace on the `<row>` elements. Does that make sense?

Comment: As a side note, having XML elements named `<row1>`, `<row2>` seems a little odd. Is this legacy system third party or an in built system? I would question the devs of the old system about why that choice was made.

Comment: yeah it is a bit odd ... looks like I would have to make use of the search and replace strategy. Thanks buddy!